# Custom dialog sometimes don't fit the screen

Tags: android, layout, dialog

I made custom dialog in my app and it looks like this:
  [image: first]

And "TEXT" is simply TextView inside a ScrollView. Height of everything is "wrap_content" to match the content and don't match the whole screen unnecessary. And everything is ok untill the text is too big and I have to scroll. Then my down part of dialog is gone and now dialog looks like this:
  [image: second]

How can I make this work well to be like this all the time?
  [image: third]

Here is the code of my custom dialog layout:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
tools:context="com.baddevelopergames.taboopremiumrebuild.DialogActivity">

<ImageView
    android:background="@drawable/ramkahg"
    android:alpha="0.8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="TEXT"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#019d92"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:id="@+id/d1_infoTextView"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:background="#019d92"
    android:alpha="0.8"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:text="BUTTON 1"
        android:id="@+id/d1_leftButton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:text="BUTTON 2"
        android:id="@+id/d1_rightButton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:background="@drawable/ramkahd"
    android:alpha="0.8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Really noone knows? :( This is the last thing to code to make my app work perfect :[

Answer (score 0):

If you want the buttons to be always on the bottom, and TEXT always above, I think you should use a RelativeLayout instead. Try with these xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    tools:context="com.baddevelopergames.taboopremiumrebuild.DialogActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:background="@drawable/ramkahg"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_above="@+id/buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="TEXT"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:background="#019d92"
                android:alpha="0.8"
                android:id="@+id/d1_infoTextView"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttons"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:background="#019d92"
            android:alpha="0.8"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
            <Button
                android:text="BUTTON 1"
                android:id="@+id/d1_leftButton"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <Button
                android:text="BUTTON 2"
                android:id="@+id/d1_rightButton"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout> 

    <ImageView
        android:background="@drawable/ramkahd"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```